# How can I handle forward slash character within a bash script?

Tags: bash, npm, package.json

In a package.json, I'm trying to replace that:

```
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
```

By that :

```
 "main": "./index.js",
 "types": "./index.d.ts",
```

So I wrote a simple script that replaces the string pattern by a dot, like so:

```
sed 's/lib\//.\//g' package.json
```

It works when I type it in the terminal.

But when it doesn't run properly when inserted in a package.json script.

**package.json:**

```
"build": "tsc && cp package.json lib/ && cd lib && sed 's/lib\//.\//g' package.json && npm publish ./lib"
```

**Output:**

```
 sed: 1: "s/lib//.//g": bad flag in substitute command: '.'
```

It keeps replacing the escaping backslash by forward slash.

How can I make it work ?

Comment: It's usually much easier if you use a `sed` delimiter other than `/` when `/` is one of the characters you want to match on. `sed 's,lib/,./,g'` for example

Comment: Are you trying to modify `package.json` from a script defined within `package.json`?

Comment: I copy it first in another location and then I modify the copy.

Comment: @JSharles Did you try the version I suggested?

Comment: @TedLyngmo    well, it throws me the amended version in terminal, but the file is not modified... I'm trying to understand

Comment: Sure, you don't modify the file. Do `sed -i 's,lib/,./,g' package.json` if you want to make modifications to the file you copied to `lib`. I wonder aboute the following `npm publish ./lib` though, since you've already `cd`:d into `lib`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo     It throws : sed: 1: "package.json": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: @JSharles Are you sure that your command line is quoted properly? There is no `p`  command in what I wrote. `package.json` is the only thing containing a `p`. Can you paste the exact `build` line that gives that error?

Comment: Adding a -e like so : sed -i -e 's,lib/,./,g' lib/package.json  make it work. But it creates another copy of the file with this name:  package.json-e

Comment: `sed -i -e 's,lib/,./,g' lib/package.json` seems wrong since you did `cd lib` after copying `package.json` to `lib`. Can you please show the exact and full `build` command?

Comment: @TedLyngmo   I removed the cd lib in order to follow your pattern. Anyway, thank you you made it work.

Comment: This is not in any way specific to bash, or zsh, or any other shell -- you'd have the same problem if you were directly invoking `sed` even with no shell at all. As such, there's no reason to tag it `bash` or `shell` or `zsh`; the only appropriate tag is `sed`.

Comment: ...that said, for editing JSON, you should really be using a syntax-aware tool like `jq`. `sed` can easily transform a valid document to an invalid one; whereas unless you tell jq you want it to emit raw output, it is literally incapable of generating invalid syntax as output (unless you count a stream of documents where only one document is expected as an invalid-syntax case).

Comment: You probably don't want to use `sed` to process JSON at all. Try something like `jq '.[] |= sub("lib"; ".")' package.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json package.json` instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Perhaps [tag:json] would be appropriate instead of the other tags since it's the json parser that "eats" the backslash aimed for `sed`?

Comment: @chepner Or instead of `cp package.json lib/package.json && cd lib && jq ...` then `jq '.[] |= sub("lib"; ".")' package.json > lib/package.json`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy   Thank you for the tool, I didn't know. But since jq needs to be installed, what if I need to share the script ?

Comment: @JSharles You can do the same in [tag:python] with 1-3 lines of code too and [tag:python] is most probably installed already.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh nice, I never used python. That's an opportunity to start I guess.

Comment: BTW, `sed -i -e ...` creating files with `-e` on the end means you're using BSD tools (like those from MacOS), instead of more Linux-typical GNU ones. For BSD sed, you want an empty string passed after `-i`, so `sed -i '' -e ...`

Comment: Why is this tagged _zsh_?

Comment: @user1934428   it's a misunderstanding on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make changes to a [json](/questions/tagged/json) document and `\` has special meaning in `json`. It's an escape character there too. You therefore need to escape your escape character:

```
s/lib\\//.\\//g
```

or give the `json` parser the unicode value for backslash:

```
s/lib\u005c//.\u005c//g
```

or simpler, don't use a forward slash as the delimiter in [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) when it's one of the characters that you want to match on:

```
sed 's,lib/,./,g'
```

Note that you are not actually modifying the document. To do that, add the `sed` option `-i`.

```
sed -i 's,lib/,./,g' package.json
```

Note: If you are using BSD tools, you need to add an empty argument to `-i`:

```
sed -i '' 's,lib/,./,g' package.json
```

or avoid that problem by *not* copying the document followed by `cd lib`. You could `sed` the original and direct the output to the new file instead:

```
sed 's,lib/,./,g' package.json > lib/package.json
```

Comment: The OP saying `sed -i -e` creates files suffixed with `-e` implies that they're using BSD tools, so they'd want `sed -i '' 's,lib/,./,g'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah... that's where that came from. Added it to the answer. Thanks!